# How to Initiate a Vonage call using a Hyperlink

Tags: html

I'm just finishing a web page for our sales guy to quickly go through a list of contacts.

Is it possible to initiate a call from our Vonage line via a Hyperlink?

They offer an application called "Click-2-Call" but I hope it's possible to initiate it using only a Hyperlink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would probably require an addon to support a custom protocol that allows your Vonage system to function in this way.

I imagine that something like

```
Call <a href="phone: 123-456-7890">123-456-7890</a>
```

Where the "phone" protocol would be recognized as a phone number that could be called by some default voip program. Then, setting Vonage to handle that protocol would allow this to work.

But, I don't believe that this is currently the case.

Comment: thanks. I'll probably just have to use their Click 2 Call application but it doesn't quite have the same flow but it will have to do for now.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this is speculation but I know skype has a browser plugin that looks at each web page and find the phone numbers and makes them clickable.  It probably just sends some info to the skype client on the machine to make the call.

I haven't seen click-2-call before.

This would be interesting to implement in an app with a PBX system as well :)

Please let us know if you find some good info!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a packet sniffer like Ethereal to see what gets sent where when you use click-2-call. It'd be pretty cool to create an outlook extension to dial my Vonage line, I don't like click-2-call very much.